# Problemas con funcion mkdir - php

Tags: php, mkdir

Les comento.

Tengo una funcion, la cual crea automaticamente un directorio segun la ruta que se le pase por una variable almacenada, la cual a esa variable se pasa un string con la ruta dinamica:

```
// Variable
private $ruta;

private function createFolder(){
   if (!is_dir($this->ruta)) {
      mkdir($this->ruta, 0777, true);
   }
}
```

El asunto, es que esta me arroja un error `mkdir(): Invalid path`, el cual antes no aparecia, ademas probe ingresando directamente la ruta a mano y ahi no me arroja el error, como por ejemplo:

```
private function createFolder(){
    if (!is_dir("assets/upload/1/")) {
        mkdir("assets/upload/1/", 0777, true);
    }
}
```

Esta funcion esta dentro de una clase que cree para la subida de archivos, al parametro de ruta paso un string, identico al que muestro arriba en la funcion que no me da error, asi que no entiendo porque el error. Comprobe los permisos y no tengo problemas con ello.
Ojala me puedan ayudar, y de antemano gracias.

Comment: Detalle: Lo extraño de todo esto, es que el directorio si lo crea sin problemas, pero sigue arrojando ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora funciona, al parecer el problema era la ruta donde estaba ubicado mi archivo, y como este era llamado desde otro lado, no tomaba bien la ruta de origen, por ello el error en el path, pero aun asi creaba la carpeta.

En resumen, la llamada al archivo se estaba realizando mal y la funcion mkdir() daba error, ya que no reconocia correctamente la ruta, pero si creaba bien el archivo.